# openVPN extremely slow, PPTP/IPsec/etc. as fast as expected

Tags: android, vpn, openvpn

I am using a VPN service that I have tested with my main tower pc to show connection speeds way above 150 MBit/s with openVPN, PPTP, IPsec, etc.

With my OnePlus One Smartphone, Android OS 6.0.1, Cyanogen OS 13.1.2 I get around  I get around 20-40 MBit/s on my normal WIfI (no VPN), using IPsec around 20 MBit/s in both direction (I have a 450 download, 20 upload connection). But as soon as I connect through any kind of OpenVPN protocoll, my download speed collapses to 0.5-2 MBit/s. The upload speed strangely does not change and stays as 20 MBit/s. The problem is 100% reproducable with my smartphone, as soon as I activate the connection, the download speed collapses, as soon as I disconnect, it instantly ramps up again. To remind you: the problem ONLY occurs with any kind of openVPN connection, when I am using PPTP, IPsec, L2TP, etc. there is no significant decline in connection speed. And it only seems to slow down DOWNLOAD speed, not UPLOAD.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using TCP or UDP?  Usually with OpenVPN you get much better bandwidth performance over the existing physical connections because there is lower overhead and OpenVPN can correct most issues anyway.  Unless you were experiencing major connectivity issues then use UDP to speed things up.
It should look like: `proto udp` as a line in your server *and* client configs.